# How to calculate SUM balance of all accounts in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table and data

```
CREATE TABLE #transactions (
    [transactionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [accountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [balance] [smallmoney] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_transactions_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [transactionId] ASC)
) 

INSERT #transactions ([transactionId], [accountId], [dt], [balance]) VALUES 
(1, 1, CAST(0x0000A13900107AC0 AS DateTime), 123.0000),
(2, 1, CAST(0x0000A13900107AC0 AS DateTime), 192.0000),
(3, 1, CAST(0x0000A13A00107AC0 AS DateTime), 178.0000),
(4, 2, CAST(0x0000A13B00107AC0 AS DateTime), 78.0000),
(5, 2, CAST(0x0000A13D011D1860 AS DateTime), 99.0000),
(6, 2, CAST(0x0000A13F00000000 AS DateTime), 97.0000),
(7, 1, CAST(0x0000A13D0141E640 AS DateTime), 201.0000),
(8, 3, CAST(0x0000A1420094DD60 AS DateTime), 4000.0000),
(9, 3, CAST(0x0000A14300956A00 AS DateTime), 4100.0000),
(10, 3, CAST(0x0000A14700000000 AS DateTime), 4200.0000),
(11, 2, CAST(0x0000A14B00B84BB0 AS DateTime), 110.0000)
```

I need two queries.

1. For each transaction, I want to return in a query the most recent balance for each account, and an extra column with a SUM of each account balance at that point in time.
2. Same as 1 but grouped by date without the time portion. So the latest account balance at the end of each day (where there is a transaction in any account) for each account, but SUMed together as in 1.

Data above is sample data that I just made up, but my real table has hundreds of rows and ten accounts (which may increase soon). Each account has a unique `accountId`. Seems quite a tricky piece of SQL.

EXAMPLE

For 1. I need a result like this:

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
| transactionId | accountId |           dt            | balance | sumBalances |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
|             1 |         1 | 2013-01-01 01:00:00.000 |     123 |         123 |
|             2 |         1 | 2013-01-01 01:00:00.000 |     192 |         192 |
|             3 |         1 | 2013-01-02 01:00:00.000 |     178 |         178 |
|             4 |         2 | 2013-01-03 01:00:00.000 |      78 |         256 |
|             5 |         2 | 2013-01-05 17:18:00.000 |      99 |         277 |
|             7 |         1 | 2013-01-05 19:32:00.000 |     201 |         300 |
|             6 |         2 | 2013-01-07 00:00:00.000 |      97 |         298 |
|             8 |         3 | 2013-01-10 09:02:00.000 |    4000 |        4298 |
|             9 |         3 | 2013-01-11 09:04:00.000 |    4100 |        4398 |
|            10 |         3 | 2013-01-15 00:00:00.000 |    4200 |        4498 |
|            11 |         2 | 2013-01-19 11:11:00.000 |     110 |        4511 |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

So, for `transactionId` 8, I take the latest `balance` for each account in turn and then sum them. `AccountID` 1: is 201, `AccountId` 2 is 97 and `AccountId` 3 is 4000. Therefore the result for `transactionId` 8 will be 201+97+4000 = 4298. When calculating the set must be ordered by `dt`

For 2. I need this

```
+------------+-------------+
|    date    | sumBalances |
+------------+-------------+
| 01/01/2013 |         192 |
| 02/01/2013 |         178 |
| 03/01/2013 |         256 |
| 05/01/2013 |         300 |
| 07/01/2013 |         298 |
| 10/01/2013 |        4298 |
| 11/01/2013 |        4398 |
| 15/01/2013 |        4498 |
| 19/01/2013 |        4511 |
+------------+-------------+
```

So on date 15/01/2013 the latest account balance for each account in turn (1,2,3) is 201,97,4200. So the result for that date would be 201+97+4200 = 4498

Comment: I'm not quite following what your desired result is. Could you add a short example?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I added an example in the question

Comment: @MooMinTroll can u elaborate how u calculate balance

Comment: `balance` is the account balance at the point in time defined in `dt` for each account (`accountId`). I am not calculating the balance, but I want to add the latest balance *for each account* at that point in time. I don't want to SUM all the balances in one account, ONLY the ones across accounts and only at each point in time, and only the latest balances at that point in time. Not sure how else to explain it. Please help me explain it! The sample data should show you what I'm after. :)

Comment: Try showing a formula for calculating sumBalances within your example, e.g. "on transactionID 5, 277 = ..."

Comment: @JohnDewey Thanks I updated the question. Hope it's clear now, if it's not please let me know

Comment: How many rows are in the table? If it is large a cursor (or CLR [equivalent](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx)) might be the best approach.

Comment: Within a year there could be 10,000 rows maybe twice that, but shouldn't be an order of magnitude larger. I'm wondering if it can be solved with temp tables or CTEs? It looks like a classic running totals problem but I can't get my brain around it. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/

Comment: @MooMinTroll - Running totals is much easier in 2012 but this is more difficult due to the need to keep track of an arbitrary number of latest balances for the other accounts.

Comment: @MartinSmith Agreed, when I sat down to write the SQL I thought it would be quite easy but there are a variable number of accounts. Conceptually it's quite simple. Just imagine you have 5 bank accounts, and you want to know how much money you have in total on any given day, or each time a transaction is made in any of your accounts. That's simply it, but translating to SQL is a little tricky...

Comment: @MooMinTroll - Ah actually that way of looking at it makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives your first desired resultset ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4070))

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                balance - 
                  isnull(lag(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId 
                                             ORDER BY dt, transactionId), 0) AS B
         FROM   #transactions)
SELECT transactionId,
       accountId,
       dt,
       balance,
       SUM(B) OVER (ORDER BY dt, transactionId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS sumBalances
FROM   T
ORDER  BY dt;
```

It subtracts the current balance of the account from the previous balance to get the net difference then calculates a running total of those differences.

And that can be used as a base for your second result

```
WITH T1
 AS (SELECT *,
            balance - 
              isnull(lag(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId 
                                         ORDER BY dt, transactionId), 0) AS B
     FROM   #transactions),
T2 AS (         
SELECT transactionId,
       accountId,
       dt,
       balance,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS DATE) ORDER BY dt DESC, transactionId DESC) AS RN,
       SUM(B) OVER (ORDER BY dt, transactionId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS sumBalances
FROM   T1)
SELECT CAST(dt AS DATE) AS [date], sumBalances
FROM T2
WHERE RN=1
ORDER  BY [date];
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it would be something along those lines, but my brain was just incapable of expressing it! Thanks, and thanks for formatting in my question too.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1**

```
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY accountId ORDER BY dt)
    FROM #transactions t
)
, b AS (
    SELECT t.*
    , transamount = t.balance - ISNULL(t0.balance,0)
    FROM a t
    LEFT JOIN a t0 ON t0.accountId = t.accountId AND t0.r + 1 = t.r
)
SELECT transactionId, accountId, dt, balance
, sumBalance = SUM(transamount)OVER(ORDER BY dt, transactionId)
FROM b
ORDER BY dt
```

**Part 2**

```
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY accountId ORDER BY dt)
    FROM #transactions t
)
, b AS (
    SELECT t.*
    , transamount = t.balance - ISNULL(t0.balance,0)
    FROM a t
    LEFT JOIN a t0 ON t0.accountId = t.accountId AND t0.r + 1 = t.r
)
, c AS (
    SELECT transactionId, accountId, dt, balance
    , sumBalance = SUM(transamount)OVER(ORDER BY CAST(dt AS DATE))
    , r1 = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY accountId, CAST(dt AS DATE) ORDER BY dt DESC)
    FROM b
)
SELECT dt = CAST(dt AS DATE)
, sumBalance
FROM c
WHERE r1 = 1
ORDER BY CAST(dt AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks John, I haven't tested your solution yet, but the advantage of yours is that it looks like it will work in SQL Server 2008 too.